# Array of Fibonacci numbers: Elements do not make sense when array size > 28

Tags: c++, arrays, iteration, fibonacci, dev-c++

I have a short C++ program that populates an array of Fibonacci numbers, then calculates the sum of the terms, and displays the sum to the screen.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    int sum = 0; // running sum
    int fib[SIZE]; // array of Fibonacci numbers

    // initialize 1st and 2nd elements = 1, the rest to 0
    for (int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++) { 
        fib[0] = 1; 
        fib[1] = 1; 
        fib[i] = 0; 
    }

    // populate the array:
    // next term in Fibonacci sequence: fib[current] - 1 + fib[current] - 2
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
        fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1]; 
        sum = sum + fib[i + 1]; 
    }

    // display the contents and the sum
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
        cout << i + 1 << ": " << fib[i] << endl; 
    }
    cout << "\nSum of the Fibonacci numbers: " << sum << endl;

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I start with `SIZE = 10`, the program adds the sum just fine...

OUTPUT:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 5
6: 8
7: 13
8: 21
9: 34
10: 55

Sum of the Fibonacci numbers: 231

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.02942 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In fact, any value of `SIZE` between 2 and 28 works well. I get the correct, positive value for the sum.

However, when I try to define `SIZE = 29` or greater, this happens:

OUTPUT:

```
1: 1
2: 32764
3: 32765
4: 65529
5: 98294
6: 163823
7: 262117
8: 425940
9: 688057
10: 1113997
.
.
.
25: 1519229809
26: -1836801828
27: -317572019
28: 2140593449
29: 1823021430

Sum of the Fibonacci numbers: 1160283831

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.05147 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't understand why the second element changed from 1 to 32764, and why I have negative values in the array when I define `SIZE = 29` or greater. Actually, I'll start getting random values and each value is unusually different after every compilation and run.

Does this relate to compilation? Maybe change data types from `int` to `long`? Did I simply run out of place holders to represent the digits? Comments are appreciated.

P.S. I've yet to rewrite this recursively. But I'm not too worried about it.

Edit: I truly appreciate the comments. I learn new things every time.

Comment: Check your indexing. Pay careful attention to what the first and last iterations of your loops will be. You've invoked undefined behavior; you're lucky you got the right answer when `SIZE == 10` (or more accurately, you were *unlucky* because it misled into believing you did it right).

Comment: It's called overflow ... integers are not infinite.

Comment: @Lightness: Could be possible that I went past the integer's range. I understand that it is not an infinite container.

Comment: @Tarion But doesn't overflow cause an exception during runtime? I didn't get any of that ):

Comment: Just a note, `fib[0]` and `fib[1]` do not need to be initialized in your first for loop. Just do it before the loop.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler have a mode where it checks the bounds of array access, etc? With gcc or clang, -fsanitize=undefined is a must to identify such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1];
   sum = sum + fib[i + 1];
}
```

For `i == 0`, you are acessing `fib[i-1]`, i.e. `fib[-1]`.
for `i == SIZE-1`, you are accessing `fib[SIZE]`.
They are causes for undefined behavior.

You need to use:

```
sum = 2; // Takes care of fib[0] and fib[1]
for (int i = 1; i < SIZE-1; i++)
{
   fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1];
   sum += fib[i + 1];
}
```

**PS**

It's important to note that `sum` overflows for values of `SIZE` greater than 44 and `fib[SIZE-1]` overflows for values of `SIZE` greater than 46 if `sizeof(int)` is 4. Use of `long` or `long long` will be necessary when `SIZE` exceeds those limits.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, from your comment, I take it that you think INT_MAX is the cause of the problem. I agree that it is also a problem but it becomes a problem only after SIZE > 46 when `sizeof(int)` is `4`.

Comment: You're confusing "fibonacci number _n_" for "sum of fibonacci numbers up to _n_".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I don't think I am but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @RSahu I was thinking about using long instead of int as it has more capacity than the int. I understand that the sum overflows for the values of SIZE greater than 44.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1]; sum = sum + fib[i + 1]; }` is writing outside the fib array. Specifically it is writing in the position `fib[i + 1]=SIZE` when `i=fib[i + 1]-1`. The same happens in the sum `sum = sum + fib[i + 1];`

Similar error happens accessing `fib[i - 1]` for `i==0`

Comment: @Lorenzo Ah of course. I realized that I didn't follow my inline comment. How silly of me. This may be a logic flaw, but I don't think the element values shouldn't change after every run.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code so you can better read the for loops.

Why do you set `fib[0]` and `fib[1]` to 1. `SIZE` times?

So fib[0] is definitely 1 afterwards :)

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
    fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1]; 
    sum = sum + fib[i + 1]; 
}
```

But regardless of the overhead in the second loop`fib[0]` is still `1` but `fib[1]` becomes `fib[0] + fib[-1]`

`fib[-1]` is a really bad index to rely on and leads to random behavior.

Here is how it works: http://cpp.sh/54dg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 30;
int main() {
    int sum = 0; // running sum
    int fib[SIZE]; // array of Fibonacci numbers

    // initialize 1st and 2nd elements = 1, the rest to 0
    for (int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++) { 
        fib[0] = 1; 
        fib[1] = 1; 
        fib[i] = 0; 
    }

    // populate the array:
    // next term in Fibonacci sequence: fib[current] - 1 + fib[current] - 2
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE-1; i++) { 
        fib[i + 1] = fib[i] + fib[i - 1]; 
        sum = sum + fib[i + 1]; 
    }

    // display the contents and the sum
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
        cout << i + 1 << ": " << fib[i] << endl; 
    }
    cout << "\nSum of the Fibonacci numbers: " << sum << endl;

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand I should've edited the format for readability. I used inline formatting to save white space lol xD But I understand that part of this is a flaw with my logic.

Comment: The only fix required is the ``for (int i = 1; i < SIZE-1; i++)``